# Bootstrap modal option

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am reading bootstrap's modal.js, where there is such snippet:

```
  $(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this)
    var href    = $this.attr('href')
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) // strip for ie7
    var option  = $target.data('bs.modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())

    if ($this.is('a')) e.preventDefault()

    $target.one('show.bs.modal', function (showEvent) {
      if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return // only register focus restorer if modal will actually get shown
      $target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
      })
    })
    Plugin.call($target, option, this)
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Anyone know what does this line `var option  = $target.data('bs.modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())` mean, especially this part `remote: !/#/.test(href) && href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `/#/` is a regular expression which searches for a hash.
- `/#/.test(href)` returns `true` if the href contains a hash.
- `!/#/.test(href)` inverts the result; it is true if the href does NOT contain a hash.
- `!/#/.test(href) && href` is a boolean AND hack. It will return `href` if the left hand side is `true`; otherwise it will return `false`.

So if the `href` contains a hash, then it outputs:

```
{ remote: false }
```

If the `href` does NOT contain a hash, it outputs:

```
{ remote: href  }
```